# Typescript Type All Props Optional

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to create an object constrained to a predefined type but without any required properties?

For example, below I'd like to provide overwrites with type `ecs.TaskDefinitionProps` but avoid the error where `compatibility`  is required because this object will only be unpacked into another object where `compatibility` is already defined.

```
import * as ecs from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecs";

// Error: Property 'compatibility' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'TaskDefinitionProps'
const taskDefinitionPropsOverrides: ecs.TaskDefinitionProps = { cpu: "512" }

const taskDefinition = new ecs.TaskDefinition(this, `TaskDefinition`, {
  compatibility: ecs.Compatibility.FARGATE,
  ...taskDefinitionPropsOverrides,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the exact use case of the `Partial<Type>` built-in utility type. It defines a new type whose properties are all the same than its input type, but marked optional.

In your case, the only change to use it is the type definition in the line with error:

```
const taskDefinitionPropsOverrides: Partial<ecs.TaskDefinitionProps> = { cpu: "512" };
```

Look at the [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `declare const` syntax in TypeScript to fix this issue. By declaring a constant of type `ecs.TaskDefinitionProps` without actually assigning any properties to it, you can create an object of that type without any required properties.

```js
import * as ecs from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecs";

declare const emptyTaskDefinitionProps: ecs.TaskDefinitionProps;

const taskDefinitionPropsOverrides: ecs.TaskDefinitionProps = { 
  ...emptyTaskDefinitionProps,
  cpu: "512"
}

const taskDefinition = new ecs.TaskDefinition(this, `TaskDefinition`, {
  compatibility: ecs.Compatibility.FARGATE,
  ...taskDefinitionPropsOverrides,
});
```

In this code, `emptyTaskDefinitionProps` is declared as a constant of type `ecs.TaskDefinitionProps`. It doesn't have any assigned properties, so it essentially acts as an empty object of that type. You can then use this constant in the spread operator (`...`) to create the `taskDefinitionPropsOverrides` object.

Reference:
[Typescript Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html)